# do loop: 'in' argument must be a nonatomic expression; found:

Tags: maxima

estoy intentando hacer esto:

```
Write a function VectorsToString, that performs the inverse procedure to StringToVectors 
Input:  An integer, n (size of blocks)
        A string, A (the alphabet)
        A list, lvec, of row vectors of size n, containing integers (in the range 0..slength(A)-1) 
Output: A string, m (the symbols corresponding to the numbers in the list)
```

He creado el siguente código, pero me aparece el error: **do loop: 'in' argument must be a nonatomic expression; found:**

```
VectorsToString(n, A, Ivec):=block(
[list:[], counter:0],
for i in Ivec do (
    counter:0,
    for j in A do (
        counter:counter+1,
        if i=contador+1 then list:append(list, j)
    )
),
print(list)

);
```

Comment: No conozco mayor cosa del lenguaje pero, es posible que no identifique el string A como una lista de elementos? Posiblemente haya que usar algo como `makelist`